# Exchange Impersonation not showing details

Tags: asp.net, exchangewebservices

I am trying to impersonate a user to get anothers users calendar to display on a web app.

I am using the following code to do this.

```
 ...
  private const string aliasUserName = "vader@mydomain.com";

 public CalendarItem[] GetCalendarItemsForUser(string userEmail, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        _exchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(aliasUserName);


        List<AttendeeInfo>userList = new List<AttendeeInfo> {new AttendeeInfo(userEmail)};
        List<CalendarItem> itemList = new List<CalendarItem>();

        GetUserAvailabilityResults availabilityResults = _exchangeService.GetUserAvailability(userList, new TimeWindow(startDate, endDate), AvailabilityData.FreeBusy);
        foreach (var item in availabilityResults.AttendeesAvailability)
        {
            foreach (var e in item.CalendarEvents)
            {
                if (e.FreeBusyStatus == LegacyFreeBusyStatus.Busy)
                {
                    CalendarItem i = new CalendarItem {Id = DateTime.Now.Millisecond};
                    if (e.Details != null)
                    {
                        i.Title = e.Details.Subject;
                        i.Location = e.Details.Location;
                    }
                    i.StartTime = e.StartTime;
                    i.EndTime = e.EndTime;
                    itemList.Add(i);
                }
            }
        }
```

This works perfectly on my development machines for all users whose calendar I am viewing.
When publishing to my production machine on the same domain. I get back the times for the appointments, but no details such as subject or location of the appointment. Again it works on my dev machine, not on the production machine. 
Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a class I created that leverages the `WinAPI` to allow for instance-based impersonation. Give this a shot and see if it helps:

```
/// <summary>
/// Leverages the Windows API (advapi32.dll) to programmatically impersonate a user.
/// </summary>
public class ImpersonationContext : IDisposable
{
    #region constants

    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

    #endregion

    #region global variables

    private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
    private bool impersonating;

    #endregion

    #region unmanaged code

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    private static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool RevertToSelf();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    #endregion

    #region constructors

    public ImpersonationContext()
    {
        impersonating = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Overloaded constructor and begins impersonating.
    /// </summary>
    public ImpersonationContext(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        this.BeginImpersonationContext(userName, password, domain);
    }

    #endregion

    #region impersonation methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Begins the impersonation context for the specified user.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Don't call this method if you used the overloaded constructor.</remarks>
    public void BeginImpersonationContext(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        //initialize token and duplicate variables
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (RevertToSelf())
        {
            if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
            {
                if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                {
                    using (WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate))
                    {
                        //begin the impersonation context and mark impersonating true
                        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        impersonating = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //close the handle to the account token
        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(token);

        //close the handle to the duplicated account token
        if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ends the current impersonation context.
    /// </summary>
    public void EndImpersonationContext()
    {
        //if the context exists undo it and dispose of the object
        if (impersonationContext != null)
        {
            //end the impersonation context and dispose of the object
            impersonationContext.Undo();
            impersonationContext.Dispose();
        }

        //mark the impersonation flag false
        impersonating = false;
    }

    #endregion

    #region properties

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the impersonation is currently active.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Impersonating
    {
        get
        {
            return impersonating;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IDisposable implementation

    ~ImpersonationContext()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);               
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (impersonationContext != null)
            {
                impersonationContext.Undo();
                impersonationContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion    
}
```

Here is how you would use the class:

```
using (ImpersonationContext context = new ImpersonationContext("user", "password", "domain"))
{
    if (context.Impersonating)
    {
        Process.Start(@"/Support/SendFax/SendFax.exe");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app pool in production needs to run with credentials that you have locally, usually just a domain user.

Answer (score 0):

Using an email address with AutodiscoverUrl does not mean that you are impersonating that user.  You also have to set the credentials and also you have to set the id of the user you wish to impersonate.  For example if you wish to log in to EWS as the current user and you wish to impersonate "vader@mydomain.com" this is how you would do it:

```
  ExchangeService service = ...;
  service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
  service.AutodiscoverUrl("vader@mydomain.com");
  service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "vader@mydomain.com");
```

Also see [MSDN on impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633680%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx) with EWS.